# Security risks in passing passwords in ftp urls

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ftp, password-protection

What are the security risks in passing passwords in ftp URLs. For instance internet explorer takes in a url of the form ftp://username:password@someserver.com.

1. Is the url transmitted in plain text?
2. Can a man in the middle (or proxy server) view the request and see the password?
3. Are there more secure ways/clients that encrypts the password across the wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes. Almost all other ways are more secure
   Check out sftp and scp

Comment: Indeed. Yes, Yes and Yes. And as a fourth point: FTP is bloody annoying on the network. Workarounds (passive mode or a FTP aware firewall) are almost always needed.

Comment: Can you recommend any web hosting company that provides sftp or equivalent?

Comment: @adentum - All honourable web hosts with shell/root access should already provide this, if not change web host.